# Escaped newlines make the code work wrong. Why?

Tags: terminal, bash, zsh

From a Markdown style guide by Google:

> Because most commandline snippets are intended to be copied and pasted directly into a terminal, it's best practice to escape any newlines. Use a single backslash at the end of the line:
>
> ```bash
> bazel run :target -- --flag --foo=longlonglonglonglongvalue \
> --bar=anotherlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglongvalue
> ```

Could someone explain why escaping newlines in the following snippet makes it work wrong if I copy-and-paste it into a terminal?

If you copy-and-paste this snippet into a terminal, it works fine:

```sh
for (( counter=10; counter>0; counter-- ))
do
echo -n "$counter "
done
printf "\n"
```

But if you copy-and-paste this one, there will be an error:

```sh
for (( counter=10; counter>0; counter-- )) \
do \
echo -n "$counter " \
done \
printf "\n"
```

Comment: The syntax for `for` requires some line separation - either by a newline, or by a semicolon. By escaping the newline, the effect is as if you would write the whole loop in a single line, without any separators. This is syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quoted example uses a backslash to escape a new line in the middle of what would normally be on one line.

Without the backslash, there would be two commands, `bazel run …` and `--bar=another…`. The second command is not a command, but just a continuation of the previous line, therefore the new line needs escaping with a backslash so that it runs 'as' one line.

The suggestion to use a backslash is instead of having a long command on one line, which would then require scrolling horizontally:

```
bazel run :target -- --flag --foo=longlonglonglonglongvalue --bar=anotherlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglongvalue
```

In your code, the new lines have meaning. Removing all the new lines creates an invalid command:

```bash
for (( counter=10; counter>0; counter-- )) do echo -n "$counter " done printf "\n"
```

This is invalid, which is why the version with the backslashes doesn't work in your case — you want the new lines as they have meaning in your code.

Answer (score 2):

The 'done' and 'printf' statements each have to be on a new line.

Comment: Not necessarily. They can also be separated by `;`.

Comment: A new logical line.